# groovy: how to pass varargs and closure in same time to a method?

Tags: groovy, closures

Given following groovy function:

```
def foo(List<String> params, Closure c) {...}
```

The method call would be:

```
foo(['a', 'b', 'c']) { print "bar" }
```

But I would like to get rid of brackets (List) in the function call. something like:

```
foo('a', 'b') { print "bar" }
```

I cannot change the list parameter to varargs because varargs can be only the last parameter in function (here the closure is the last one).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13):

Seeing that it's impossible to achieve exactly what you want (it's written in Groovy documentation that your specific case is a problem, unfortunately they are migrating the docs so I can't directly link right now), what about something along these lines:

```
def foo(String... params) {
    println params
    return { Closure c ->
        c.call()
    }
}

foo('a', 'b') ({ println 'woot' })
```

Now you need to put the closure in parantheses, but you don't need to use an array anymore..

Answer (score 10):

I think this only could be possible if you use an array as argument or an [Variable-Length Argument List](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060106/VariableLengthArgumentLists.html) :

```
def foo(Object... params) {
    def closureParam = params.last()
    closureParam()
}

foo('a', 'b') { print "bar" }
```

Comment: This is the solution i tend to avoid, because i won't have control on the parameter types any more. one can send integer or other object instead of string.

Comment: @mhshams you would have that control with `String... strings` varargs

Comment: nm, I think I understand now that you need `Closure c` as final arg.

Comment: `foo(def... params)` will make it look slightly more Groovy than Java-esque, if you have to resort to this anyway.

Answer (score 9):

There's always Poor Man's Varargs™

```
def foo(String p1,                                  Closure c) {foo [p1],             c}
def foo(String p1, String p2,                       Closure c) {foo [p1, p2],         c}
def foo(String p1, String p2, String p3,            Closure c) {foo [p1, p2, p3],     c}
def foo(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, Closure c) {foo [p1, p2, p3, p4], c}
...
```

I'm only half joking.

Answer (score -4):

Switch to Kotlin ;-)

```
fun test(vararg s: String, c: ()->String) {
    println(s)
    println(c())
}
```

Working like a charm...