# Checking multiple lists for emptiness in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Let's say I've got three lists with objects

```
List<String> list1, list2, list3
```

What is the best way to do check whether any of them is not empty and do some action?

So far I came up with

```
if ([list1, list2, list3].any()) {
    // do some action
}
```

But is there a way to omit `if` block at all?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  Why would you want to?  Wouldn't readability suffer?

Comment: @tim_yates well I do not care about readability there. All I want to make it as small as possible to the maximum possible extent. Originally It relied on `if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list1) || ...)` by the way

Comment: you could do `Optional.of((a + b + c)[0]).ifPresent { println 'not empty' }` if youre on java 8...  but yuk, and not shorter

Comment: Is the action you want to do applied on the objects of the non-empty lists? In that case, maybe `[list1, list2, list3].findAll().each { ... }` is what you are looking for.

Comment: in action I do something like `item.addKeyItems(KEY, list1, list2, list3)` so `each` wont' work there

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there can be anything better than

```
if (list1 || list2 || list3) {
}
```

You want some kind of `NotEmptyPredicate(l1, l2, l3).ifMatch { println 'hi' }`, but it does not exist in standard library. Creating one is not worth.

Comment: I see. Though I think `[list1, list2, list3]` is better than `(list1 || list2 || list3)` as it more versatile

Comment: @user1432980 in what way more versatile?

Comment: @tim_yates, for example if I have to check more lists than those three. Storing them in the list `def lists = [list1, list2, list3]` I can then do `if (lists.any())`. If I need to add additional list check I can simple add it to `lists` like `def lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]` but the whole `if` won't change. Also It will be less verbose if I add additional checks to `if` block (not only ||)

Comment: @user1432980 fair enough, but you'll still have to change your call to `item.addKeyItems(KEY, list1, list2, list3)` if your underlying dataset expands?

Comment: @tim_yates, the problem is that  code was in `java`, designed with `java` in mind and etc. Reorganizing it may lead to something better. I am just doing refactoring of java code using groovy. Because currently `addKeyItems` is defined as  `addKeyItems(String type, List<Item> list1, List<Item> list2, List<Item> list3)`

Answer (score 0):

One objective part of your question is about omitting the `if` block. This answer pertains to that. I don't recommend this for production code, nor do I claim this is the *best* way, which is subjective.

Generally, if statements can be "hidden" by using maps. (The context is a new static method on `List`, via Groovy's meta-programming):

```
List.metaClass.static.ifNotEmpty = { List<String>... lists ->
    def resultMap = [:]

    resultMap[true] = { Closure c -> c.call() }
    resultMap[false] = { Closure c -> }

    return resultMap[lists.any()]
}
```

Here are example usages... See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406559/groovy-how-to-pass-varargs-and-closure-in-same-time-to-a-method) to understand the unusual syntax of `({ })`

```
List<String> list1, list2, list3

list1 = []
list2 = null
list3 = []
list3 << "HELLO"

List.ifNotEmpty(list1, list2, list3) ({ println "test 1" })

list1 = []
list2 = null
list3 = []

List.ifNotEmpty(list1, list2, list3) ({ println "should not see this" })
```